# How to upload video file into wowza media server in android?

Tags: android, live-streaming, android-video-player

Hi i m very new to wowza media server. Can any body tell me how to upload video file or live streaming in android using wowza? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending live video stream to wowza streaming engine with Android devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953555/sending-live-video-stream-to-wowza-streaming-engine-with-android-devices)