# Sending live video stream to wowza streaming engine with Android devices

Tags: android, live-streaming, wowza

I want to send live video stream from my android device to wowza streaming engine. I am using sample in this [blog](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg) but I can not see the result on `Test Players` page.

Do I need to have a web server serving a page with a video player pointed to this video/app on wowza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this little (but very useful) library with three examples: [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/wiki/Using-libstreaming-with-Wowza-Media-Server)
It works like a charm! Easy to install and develop.

Answer (score 0):

Main point is to look at Wowza logs to understand if stream was successfully published or not.
Then, according to logs you will know what Application, Application instance and Stream name are used for publishing.
So you'll be able to set up any player (VLC for example) with those values and look if stream is viewable or not.

Comment: for linux: /usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/logs or /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/logs   
for windows smth like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is ok. Libstreaming is working (kinda) but it did not fulfill my expectations so that it can be pushed to some production app. Since this question is quite old, i will share mine up-to-date solution (AS 2.1.2 - Marshmallow) which is using JavaCV. I've built boilerplate for android so it can be used in no time.

Here is url: 
[How to stream live video from android to Wowza via RTMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120116/how-to-stream-live-video-from-android-to-wowza-via-rtmp)